# How to read and convert a SAS dataset (hosted on S3) into AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, sas, amazon-rds

I am trying to migrate my SAS data from my s3 to aws RDS. I realize that most likely the only way to query data on AWS RDS/Aurora is through MySQL. I would like to know how to read in these SAS data files from S3, convert them to MySQL tables and store it back on S3, and query it when I want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SAS installed? I would suggest using Sqlite vs MySql.

Comment: Yes, I have SAS installed. Does Sqlite work with AWS RDS and S3?

Comment: I am unsure on that. Work on the connection string. SAS to Sqlite is: libname sqlite odbc complete="dsn=SQLite3 Datasource;Driver={SQLITE3 ODBC Driver};Database=e:\temp\TEMP.db";
libname temp 'e:\temp' ;
 
data sqlite.IISHistorical;
   set temp.All_iis_old;
run;

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the file down to a local drive or perhaps a server. You could use Proc S3 or a filename statement.

```
FILENAME frefget S3 'fileOne.dta'
REGION     = '{your region}'                 
KEYID      = '{your username}'      
SECRET     = '{your password}'   
BUCKETNAME = 'bucketOne';              

DATA work.dataOne;                             
    infile frefget;                          
    input;                                   
    put _infile_;                            
run;
```

OR

```
PROC S3 REGION='{your region name here}'
        KEYID ='{your keyid here}'
        SECRET='{your secret key here}';
    GET 'bucketOne/fileOne.dta' '{your drive and path}/fileOne.dta';
    // Note: Use your OSs slashes in the 2nd parameter in the GET statement.
    //       Use AWS *nix slashes in the 2st parameter.
RUN;
```

Next, with the file downloaded, you can define an SQL statement to create yourself an SQL format dataset.
You could use a SAS datastep to correctly form your data ready for your upload to AWS RDS.

e.g.

```
FILENAME f1 '{your drive and path}/fileOne.dta';

DATA WORK.dataOne;
    set f1;
    ... some formatting work here;
    output;
RUN;
```

Next, create your dataset in a MySql database.

```
libname db MYSQL user={username here}
                 password={password here}
                 database={db name here}
                 server={db servername here}
                 port=3306;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE db.tableOne AS
    SELECT *
    FROM dataOne
    ...;
QUIT;
```